# Incorrect number of bindings supplied - Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am using Pydev in eclipse with a mySQL connector. I was writing code to take information from the codes output and put it into the database. But I receive the error

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 0 supplied.
```

Here is the code for, any help would be appreciated:

```
try:
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE ipinfo
           (SEARCH_ASN TEXT NOT NULL,
           SEARCH_ASN_CIDR TEXT NOT NULL,
           SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE TEXT NOT NULL,
           SEARCH_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
           SEARCH_REGISTRY TEXT NOT NULL)''')
    print "Table created successfully";
except:
    pass

cursor.close()


object = IPWhois('ip address')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
cursor = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ipinfo(SEARCH_ASN, SEARCH_ASN_CIDR, SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE, SEARCH_DATE, SEARCH_REGISTRY) \
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)")
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

results takes info froom an ip using a webcrawler

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ipinfo(SEARCH_ASN, SEARCH_ASN_CIDR, SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE, SEARCH_DATE, SEARCH_REGISTRY) \
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)")
```

you're sending an paramerized `insert` query, but you do not provide the values to insert. This should look something like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ipinfo(SEARCH_ASN, SEARCH_ASN_CIDR, SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE, SEARCH_DATE, SEARCH_REGISTRY)           VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
values = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)     
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

I assume you want to get your values from your `results` variable but since we don't know what `results` is we can't help further.

Comment: Okay thanks very much. The results are information about an ip address supplied with a web crawler. Sorry for not being more specific

Answer (score 0):

You have not supplied any data.
An insert statement looks like this (for example):

```
new_db.execute("insert into Recent(Filename,TimeStamp,Icon) values (?,?,?)", \
                (x['Filename'],x['TimeStamp'],x['Icon']))
```